# How to solve predicate error in a method c#

Tags: c#, lambda, abstract-class, predicate

I have a method inside a generic abstract class in C#, but it appears that once I run the application:

```
System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter: Invoke(value(...), {document}).
```

and the code that yields the error:

```cs
public I Get<I>(string id, IBsonSerializer<I> serializer = null, Predicate<M> condition) where I : IModelBase =>
            Items.Find(M => M.Id == id && condition(M)).As(serializer).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now the problem is with `Find` invocation so you can ignore other code around that.

I found that I can replace the `condition(M)` part with `(condition ?? (ignore => true))(M)` but even that didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `Items`?

Comment: @Llama It's a `IMongoCollection<M>` - collection like interface. Now i'm pretty sure it's just the problem inside `Find` that needs focus here...

Comment: Is `M` a type? Or a type variable defined in the class that this method is defined in? Or something else?

Comment: What is `Predicate<M>`? So this is related to mongo? Your question is missing quite a lot of context, making it hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/93614cccfa52d34a5807477df614aee6a2beb0a6/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Linq2Implementation/Translators/PredicateTranslator.cs#L73-L147

In this code snippet we can see the PredicateTranslator didn't handle the expression with the 'Invoke' node type.
You can try to make the condition no longer part of the expression, for example, first calculate the value of the condition outside the lambda.

Comment: Thank you, but I decided to extend the method for a few more...

Comment: public I Get<I>(string id, IBsonSerializer<I> serializer = null, Predicate<M> condition) where I : IModelBase {  var b= condition(M);
            Items.Find(M => M.Id == id && b).As(serializer).FirstOrDefault();}